# child item not matching the constraint in Constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have to convert one my existing complex layout to flat `ConstaintLayout`. So I designed one and it is perfectly aligned in the android studio preview Window

[image: Adnroid Studio design]

> xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout13"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_on"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_view_on_selector"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="ON"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_on"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tv_off"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guidelineOnOff"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_off"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_off"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_view_off_selector"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="OFF"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_off"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guidelineOnOff"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_on"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineOnOff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="45dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivIntensityIncrement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/sb_intensity"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/sb_intensity"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineOnOff"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivWCIncrement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/sb_warmCool"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/sb_warmCool"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/sb_warmCool"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineOnOff"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

<com.samsung.lighting.presentation.ui.custom_views.VerticalSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sb_intensity"
    style="@style/intensitySeekBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="30"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb_gray"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ivIntensityDecrement"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/cp_rgb"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivIntensityIncrement"
    app:rotate_angle="90" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivIntensityDecrement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnFanOff"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/sb_intensity"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/sb_intensity" />

<com.samsung.lighting.rgb.ColorPicker
    android:id="@+id/cp_rgb"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/sb_warmCool"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/sb_intensity"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelineOnOff" />

<com.samsung.lighting.presentation.ui.custom_views.VerticalSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sb_warmCool"
    style="@style/warmSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="30"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ivWCDecrement"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cp_rgb"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivWCIncrement"
    app:rotate_angle="-90" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivWCDecrement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_black"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnFanOff"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/sb_warmCool"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/sb_warmCool"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sb_warmCool" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFanOff"
    style="@style/buttonFanKnob"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/_0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cb_allDevice"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnSpeedLow"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSpeedLow"
    style="@style/buttonFanKnob"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/_1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cb_allDevice"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnSpeedMedium"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnFanOff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSpeedMedium"
    style="@style/buttonFanKnob"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/_2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cb_allDevice"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnSpeedHigh"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnSpeedLow" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSpeedHigh"
    style="@style/buttonFanKnob"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/_3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cb_allDevice"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgRotateClockWise"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnSpeedMedium" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgRotateClockWise"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/right_up_arrow"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cb_allDevice"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/swhSwing" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/swhSwing"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cb_allDevice"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgRotateCounterClockWise" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgRotateCounterClockWise"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/left_up_arrow"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cb_allDevice"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_allDevice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="All Devices"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll_cancel"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ll_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/ok1"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ll_cancel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ll_reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/alert.button.reset"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ll_cancel"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ll_cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/alert.button.cancel"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ll_ok"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ll_reset" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_intensity"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_warmCool"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

The problem was the `VerticalSeekbar` is not aligning as shown like this.

[image: real rendered image in device]

> VerticalSeekbar

```
  @Override
protected final void onDraw(@NonNull final Canvas c) {
    c.rotate(ROTATION_ANGLE_270);
    c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);
    super.onDraw(c);
}
```

The view's visibility set by dynamically. So Some of the views are may be visible or not visible at some time. If the buttons are not visible the seekbar must increase the height. But it is not happening. Always the seekbar height is 0dp. It is violating the match constraint attribute.

Comment: Which version of ConstraintLayout are you using? Try 1.1.0 which is the latest production version.

Comment: Yes I am using v1.1.0

Comment: That's good. Your three bottom buttons are only constrained vertically by a constraint from the bottom of the buttons to the bottom of the parent. They seem to be riding much higher in the layout and that can't be right. Check that the parent layout extends down as far as it appears by using the layout inspector or just give it a background color.